# Preshared keys (TLS-PSK-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA) with node.js server

Tags: node.js, ssl

I'm trying to implement a server that can field a request from a very constrained client that wants to handshake using pre-shared keys (PSK) using the cryptosuite TLS-PSK-WITH-AES-256 with a node.js server. I can't seem to find any samples or documentation that talks about how you'd set this up.  Is this cryptosuite supported by node.js?  If so, how does one go about configuring the options for the https server to accept these connections and verify them?

Answer (score 2):

Although [`tls.getCiphers()`](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_getciphers) claims to support `psk-aes256-cbc-sha`, it appears that [support is not actually implemented](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26/lib/tls.js#L1032).

Someone did submit a [pull request](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/1162/files) implementing PSK several years ago, but it apparently went stale and was never merged.

To get PSK working, you'll have to manually apply the changes from the old PR to the current version of node and create a custom build.