# Using Node.js MQTT with Mosquitto PSK Encryption

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm working on developing a solution using MQTT to send/receive data to embedded systems. For a broker I'm using [Mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org/).  For the client I'm using [Node.js MQTT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt).

I need to encrypt the data and I'd like to use the pre-shared key option in mosquitto to accomplish this however, I can't seem to find anything built into the Node.js MQTT package to do this.  Is this possible?

From the Mosquitto configuration docs:

> When using pre-shared-key based encryption through the psk_hint and
>   psk_file options, the client must provide a valid identity and key in
>   order to connect to the broker before any MQTT communication takes
>   place. If use_identity_as_username is true, the PSK identity is used
>   instead of the MQTT username for access control purposes. If
>   use_identity_as_username is false, the client may still authenticate
>   using the MQTT username/password if using the password_file option.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm betting not. Support for TLS-PSK isn't very widespread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node does [support TLS-PSK](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#pre-shared-keys) now, but PSK ciphers are [disabled by default](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#modifying-the-default-tls-cipher-suite).
I finally could connect with the following options:

```
const client  = mqtt.connect('mqtts://localhost:8883', {
  pskCallback: (hint) => {
    console.log('psk_hint configured in mosquitto.conf', hint);
    return {
      psk: Buffer.from('1234', 'hex'),
      identity: 'DeviceId',
    };
  },
  ciphers: crypto.constants.defaultCipherList.replace(':!PSK', ''),
});
```

`psk_file` must include the line `DeviceId:1234` in this example.
My main problem was, that configuring a custom ciphers list must include `HIGH` for whatever reason. It even works with `ciphers: 'HIGH'`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the MQTT package hands off to Node's TLS capabilities and Node doesn't support TLS PSK.

[Preshared keys (TLS-PSK-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA) with node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998229/preshared-keys-tls-psk-with-aes-256-cbc-sha-with-node-js-server)